# Converting String of Tuple into Tuple

Tags: python

How to convert a string in Python into a Tuple without splitting the words into characters?

String: `"('name','value')"`

Expected Output: `('name', 'value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use module `ast`

```
>>> a = "('name','value')"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a)
('name', 'value')
```